# Какая-то глупая ошибка в проекте на C++ с использованием Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте! Пишу на Qt простую программу, которая моделирует броуновское движение частицы. Хочу, чтоб программа делала 10 шагов. Вместо этого мне почему-то рисуется лишь 6 кружочков (казалось бы, дело в том, что шаг у меня часто равен нулю), но что она выводит, я вообще не понимаю, почему-то вывод вдвое длиннее ожидаемого мной. Если вместо 10 шагов использовать 100 шагов, то всё смещается куда-то вверх (в область меньших y, как я понимаю). Хотя, как мне кажется, траектория-то должна начинаться из точки (250, 250) в любом случае. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём у меня может быть ошибка.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <unistd.h>


double PI_F = 3.141592653589;


class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    double T = 10; // Температура
    double C = 1;  // Вязкость
    double x = 250;
    double y = 250;
    double scale = 50;
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawEllipse(x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
            double angle = (rand() % 360) / (2 * PI_F);
            double dr = rand() % (int)(C + 1);
            double newx = x + scale * dr * cos(angle);
            double newy = y + scale * dr * sin(angle);
            painter.drawLine(x, y, newx, newy); 
            if(newx > 0 && newx < 500 && newy > 0 && newy < 500)
                painter.drawEllipse(newx - 3, newy - 3, 6, 6);
            x = newx;
            y = newy;
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyWidget myWidget;
    myWidget.resize(500, 500);
    myWidget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Вот на всякий случай то, что выводится в консоль.

```
250 250
250 250
200.526 242.769
232.956 204.713
232.956 204.713
215.357 251.513
257.524 278.383
252.345 328.114
252.345 328.114
252.345 328.114
252.345 328.114
252.345 328.114
266.675 376.017
266.675 376.017
221.498 354.592
229.754 305.278
229.754 305.278
229.754 305.278
237.332 255.856
237.332 255.856
```

Comment: Моя система Linux Mint, для сборки использую qmake -project; qmake; make

Comment: Замена for на while с условием рисовать пока шарик в пределах виджета тоже приводит к какому-то странному результату, в итоге точки вообще не отображаются, ни одна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, нужно обновление координат убрать из PaintEvent. Надо, например, написать собственную функцию updateCoordinates(), в которой будут пересчитываться новые координаты, и из updateCoordinates() вызывать метод update().